# SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated in snowflake DB

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing Unsupported Subquery error in the snowflake DB. But in the same query is working fine in the ORACLE DB.

> SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Example :

```
SELECT A.EMPNO,A.ENAME,D.DEPTNO
       FROM EMP E
       LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPT D
       ON E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
       AND D.EFFDT = 
                    (SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM DEPT E WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO)
```

When I try this code into snowflake it is showing error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you can have many equal `EFFDT` per `DEPTNO` and which point to want to use a RANK or MAX

OR if you only want the single best `EFFDT` per `DEPTNO` at which point I would use a ROW_NUMBER()

So if you want to filter at the end I would use:

```
SELECT 
    E.EMPNO,
    E.ENAME,
    D.DEPTNO
FROM EMP E
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPT D
    ON E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY D.DEPTNO ORDER BY D.EFFDT DESC) = 1
```

OR you can filter before the join:

```
SELECT 
    e.empno,
    e.ename,
    d.deptno
FROM emp AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT z.effdt, z.deptno
    FROM dept AS z
    QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY z.DEPTNO ORDER BY z.EFFDT DESC) = 1
) as d
    ON e.deptno = d.deptno
```

thus with these great fake data CTE's:

```
WITH emp(empno, ename, deptno) as (
    select * from values
    (1,'emp_1', 10),
    (2,'emp_2', 20)
), dept(effdt, other, deptno) as (
   select * from values
    (111, 'row1', 10),
    (221, 'row2', 20),
    (222, 'row3', 20)
)
```

```
SELECT 
    e.empno,
    e.ename,
    d.deptno,
    d.other
FROM emp AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT z.effdt, z.deptno, z.other
    FROM dept AS z
    QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY z.deptno ORDER BY z.EFFDT DESC) = 1
) as d
    ON e.deptno = d.deptno
```

gives:

| EMPNO | ENAME | DEPTNO | OTHER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emp_1 | 10 | row1 |
| 2 | emp_2 | 20 | row3 |

Comment: Hi Simeon, Thank you for your quick update.